# ASP.Net can't see my database from the ISS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I decided to learn how to make a simple ASP.Net project, with a *reference* to a database project through the Repository Pattern.

I have my Controller calling for a `List<Weight>` to handle:

```
public IActionResult MyWeight()
{
    var repo = new Database.Repositories.WeightRepository();
    var data = repo.GetWeight().Result;

    return View(data);
}
```

When `repo.GetWeight()` is called, I get an `AggregateException` error, with an inner exception saying:

```
"No connection string named 'MyDatabaseConnection' could be found in the application config file."
```

So for clarity, let me outline the solution's structure:

- aspProj

  - Controllers
  - Views
  - Service
  - App.config (1)
  - Web.config
  - ...
- Database

  - Entities
  - Repositories
  - App.config (2)
  - ...
- Database.Test

  - Test.cs
  - App.config (3)
  - ...

I've added the following `connectionString` to all `App.config`s and the `Web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add
        name="MyDatabaseConnection"
        connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I have tested the database both from Visual Studio's `Server Explorer`, and through the `Test.cs` file from the test-project. I can insert data and retrieve without a problem.
But when the ASP.Net-part wants to access it, there is no love.

I thought it might be the ISS which did not know the path from where it is...

Any thoughts?

__

**Edit:**

My Web.config:
[image]

My AppSetting.json:
[image]

Comment: The asp.net project only needs the one `web.config` file. The connection string will go in the `<connectionStrings></connectionStrings>` section of the web config file.

Comment: Like what I did in the **edit**?

Comment: What version is your asp project? I'm noticing that you have 'JSON' for your app settings

Comment: Your web.config doesn't have a `MyDatabaseConnection` connection from what I can tell. It has a `WeightDatabaseConnection`. Either change the name or add a new connection string.

Comment: I think that you are way out there if you are searching after your database from ISS. A bonus point for the effort though, becoming an astronaut isn't easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the problem is clear - ASP.NET is trying to access the database using a connection string with the name **MyDatabaseConnection**:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDatabaseConnection" connectionString="put the connection to the db here..." />
  </connectionStrings>
```

And in your Web.config you only have a connection string with the name **WeightDatabaseConnection**:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="WeightDatabaseConnection" connectionString="put the connection to the db here..." />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Just add a new element for MyDatabaseConnection under `<connectionStrings>` in the **Web.config** file and it should work